# @font-face issue - Typeface doesn't look the same as within the kit

Tags: html, css, font-face

This is driving me insane I've ran the District Thin typeface through @font-face and got the kit however it doesn't look quite right compared to within the kit. I've followed the process right it seems because other typefaces I used have all rendered correct. What am I doing wrong? I've noticed the '&' doesn't look right either. Heres an example of my code.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'district_prothin';
src: url('../fonts/distproth-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/distproth-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/distproth-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/distproth-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/distproth-webfont.svg#district_prothin') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

`h2 {
    font-size: 8.9em;
    font-family: district_prothin, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: what does your browser console say? Any warnings about it refusing to load the fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have that font installed on your local machine with the same name, by any chance? 
If so, try renaming the font family (both declaration & usage)...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Some Random Name';

  /* ... */

font-family: 'Some Random Name', sans-serif;
```

Otherwise maybe take a look at this blog post http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ . try to embed your font like this. Works for me all the time...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
         url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff')
```

Comment: Tried this but its still not working. It just seems weird that it works perfectly within the kit demo but not in my code. The other typefaces I've used within @font-face seem to be rendering fine?